# Installation of ubuntu 12.04 from pen drive

Tags: boot, system-installation

I made the pen drive bootable by using following link 
http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

But after installation is finished successfully. It is telling unable to load OS. If i am trying to reinstall it is showing a ubuntu is installed already . Please guide me appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Try re-installing the Grub bootloader again. To do that use your live USB and boot into Ubuntu 12.04 and install boot-repair with the following commands:

sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

Use advanced options(at left bottom) in boot-repair(not the recommended).

Open advanced options in boot-repair .

advanced options=>'GRUB location' (Select "place grub into". Select "sda". Don't select sda1 or sda2 or anything like those numbered partitions. Just choose 'sda' only)

advanced options=>'GRUB options' (Select "Purge grub before reinstalling it")

advanced options=> Other options ( Unselect the "Repair Windows boot files" & "Check Internet connection" if they are selected.)

Comment: Problem solved  after reinstalling grub.

Comment: But now touchpad is not working I tried                        sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics

Comment: But now touchpad is not working I tried sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics but after sucessfull installation nothing worked out.

Comment: Problem solved by one of the links suggesting that there can be a key combination for touchpad lock.